# How to look up and fill in data in dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matching

```
for i, row in lst.iterrows():
     value1 = a
     value2 = b
     result = 12345

     if df[(df['column1'] == value1) & (df['column2'] == value2)]:
          df['column_result'] == result 

print df
```

I want to look up in a dataframe a row where column1 equals value1 and column2 equals value2 **and** fill in result in that row.

I receive this error:
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df.loc[(df['column1'] == value1) & (df['column2'] == value2), 'column_result'] = result
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ChristianVandeKoppel, do consider accepting the answer, it helps in closing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `or` and `and` python statements require truth-values. For pandas these are considered ambiguous so you should use "bitwise" `|` (or) or `&` (and) operations:

```
result = result[(result['var']>0.25) | (result['var']<-0.25)]
```

These are overloaded for these kind of datastructures to yield the element-wise `or` (or `and`).

More Info Here : [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)